# Pass the multiple checkbox values from parent window to popup window

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am working on JSP's, I am not able to pass the checkbox values from parent window to child window, in my parent window i have some options to select , if i have selected multiple checkboxes, the selected checkboxes must be pass to the child window for furthur use.. but i am not able to get those, could anyone please help me out..

Comment: What have you try, please post some code (using jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1"
                                        align="center" bgcolor="#74f0a8" width="90%">
                                        <font size="4" color="#c7461e"><b>CHEQUE ACTIVATION
                                                REPORT BETWEEN : <s:property value='strChequeFrom' /> AND :
                                                <s:property value='strChequeTo' /> </b> </font>
                                        <tr>

                                            <td colspan="7" align="center" width="10%">
                                                <b>SL NO</b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <b>AGENCY</b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <b>CLIENT ADDRESS</b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <b>CHEQUE NO</b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <b>CHEQUE DATE</b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <b>CHEQUE AMOUNT</b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <b>ACTIVATION</b>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <s:iterator status="rowstatus" value="lstChequeDateReportDetail">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="7" align="center" width="10%">
                                                    <font size="3"><s:property value="jsp_sl_no" /> </font>
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <s:property value="strAgencyCode" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <s:property value="strClient" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <s:property value="strChequeNo" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <s:property value="strChequeDate" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <s:property value="strPaymanetAmount" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <table>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>


    <s:checkbox name="strActivationCheque" fieldValue="%{strChequeNo}" value="false"/>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </s:iterator>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <s:submit value="Activate"></s:submit>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
```

See this example ..Its an iteration process, by this you will get the checked(true) check box list in action page with the value of "strChequeNo". You can use any other primary value on "strChequeNo"